# How to combine tax_query and date_query in Wordpress

Tags: wp-query, woocommerce-offtopic, tax-query, date-query

I'm using the following query to extract all products which are not in the 'Service' product category and order them by a custom meta field '_vintage_age'.

```
$q->set( 'tax_query', array(array(
    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
    'field' => 'slug',
    'terms' => array( 'Service' ),  
    'operator' => 'NOT IN'
)));

$q->set('meta_query',array(array(
    'vtp_age' => array(
    'key' => '_vintage_age',
    'value' => array(1,2,3),
    'compare' => 'IN'
))));

$q->set('orderby',array(
    'vtp_age' => 'ASC',
    'date' => 'ASC'
));
```

I now need to extend this query to EXCLUDE products which have been modified with the product_category 'Sold' more than 1 month ago (ie. display all unsold, non serviced products and all products sold in the last month). My guess is to use something like this, but how do I apply this to 'Sold' products only AND add it to my original query?

```
array(
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'column' => 'post_modified_gmt',
            'after'  => '1 month ago',
        ),
))
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid that there is no way to do such advanced queries using WP_Query.

But, of course, you can still achieve that result, but you'll need to write a little bit more code.

There are two solutions:

It's hard to give you precise code, because there aren't many details in your question, but maybe this will be enough :)

### 1. Use `posts_where` and `posts_join` filters

If you're not afraid of writing your own SQL queries, then you can use `posts_where` and `posts_join` filters to add some more advanced SQL conditions to your WP_Query.

### 2. Use second WP_Query and then exclude these posts

If you don't like raw SQL, then you can use second WP_Query. Use it to select all posts that you want to exclude. Then you can use their IDs and pass them as `post__not_in` param to your current WP_Query - this way you will exclude them.

Comment: @RichardTinkler No problem :)